# Preciso que o arquivo liste uma pasta específica

Tags: php

Preciso que este arquivo liste uma pasta que seja definida manualmente. Atualmente ele lista o diretório onde o arquivo está, gostaria de listar por exemplo: `/arquivos`

```
<?php

// pega o endereço do diretório
$diretorio = getcwd();
// abre o diretório
$ponteiro  = opendir($diretorio);
// monta os vetores com os itens encontrados na pasta
while ($nome_itens = readdir($ponteiro)) {
    $itens[] = $nome_itens;
}

//O que fizemos aqui, foi justamente, pegar o diretório, abri-lo e lê-lo.

//Continuando, vamos usar:
//sort: ordena os vetores (arrays), de acordo com os parâmetros informados. Aqui estou ordenando por pastas e depois arquivos

// ordena o vetor de itens
sort($itens);
// percorre o vetor para fazer a separacao entre arquivos e pastas
foreach ($itens as $listar) {
// retira "./" e "../" para que retorne apenas pastas e arquivos
   if ($listar!="." && $listar!=".."){

// checa se o tipo de arquivo encontrado é uma pasta
                if (is_dir($listar)) {
// caso VERDADEIRO adiciona o item à variável de pastas
                        $pastas[]=$listar;
                } else{
// caso FALSO adiciona o item à variável de arquivos
                        $arquivos[]=$listar;
                }
   }
}

//Vimos acima, a expressão is_dir, indicando que as ações devem esntão ser executadas, ali mesmo, no diretório que já //foi aberto e lido. As ações que executamos ali, foram: ver se tem pastas, listar. Ver se tem arquivos, listar.

//Agora, se houverem pastas, serão apresentadas antes dos arquivos, em odem alfabética.
//Se não houverem, serão apresentados apenas os arquivos, na mesma ordem.
//E se houverem os dois, serão mostrados igualmente.

// lista as pastas se houverem

if ($pastas != "" ) {
foreach($pastas as $listar){
   $pastas = $listar;
   echo "<li><a href='$listar'><strong>Pasta: </strong>$listar</a></li>" ;
   }
   }
// lista os arquivos se houverem
if ($arquivos != "") {
foreach($arquivos as $listar){
   $arquivos = $listar;
   $tamanho = "";
   if ( (filesize($arquivos) > 1024)&&(filesize($arquivos) < (1024 * 1000)) ) // KBYTE
                $tamanho = number_format((filesize($arquivos) / 1024),2)." Kb";
   elseif(filesize($arquivos) > (1024 * 1000)) //MBYTE
        $tamanho = number_format((filesize($arquivos) / (1024 * 1024)),2)." Mb";
   else $tamanho = number_format(filesize($arquivos),2)." bytes";

    if($arquivos == 'index.php' || $arquivos == 'error_log' || $arquivos == 'menu_cond_online.php' || $arquivos == 'functions.php' || $arquivos == 'formulario_login.php' || $arquivos == 'logo.jpg' || $arquivos == 'arquivos.php'
    || $arquivos == 'index.html' || $arquivos == '.gitignore' || $arquivos == '.jshintrc' || $arquivos == 'CONTRIBUTING.md' || $arquivos == 'Gruntfile.js' || $arquivos == 'README.md' || $arquivos == 'angularjs.html'
    || $arquivos == 'basic-plus.html' || $arquivos == 'basic.html' || $arquivos == 'blueimp-file-upload.jquery.json' || $arquivos == 'bower.json' || $arquivos == 'jquery-ui.html' || $arquivos == 'listaarquivos.php' || $arquivos == 'package.json')

                echo "";
        else
                echo "<li><a href='$listar'>$listar</a>  ", "Enviado em: " . date ("d/M/Y - ", filemtime(       $arquivos)) ,  "Tamanho: ",$tamanho."</li>";
   }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta alterar as seguintes linhas:

```
// pega o endereço do diretório
$diretorio = getcwd();
// abre o diretório
$ponteiro  = opendir($diretorio);
```

Para:

```
// abre o diretório
$ponteiro  = opendir(__DIR__ . '/arquivos');
```

Comment: agora estou com seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined variable: pastas in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivos\arquivos.php on line 41

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for A3_CPU.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivos\arquivos.php on line 52

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for A3_CPU.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivos\arquivos.php on line 54

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for A3_CPU.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivos\arquivos.php on line 56

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma maneira mais fácil de listar um diretório no PHP. Isso pode ser feito através da classe `FileSystemIterator`;

Veja em pequeno exemplo:

```
        $fileIt = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__ . '/arquivos');

        foreach($fileIt as $file) {

            if ($file->isFile()) {
                echo 'caminho completo: ', $file->getRealPath(), '<br>', 
                     'nome: ', $file->getFilename(), '<br>', 
                     'tamanho: ', $file->getSize(), '<br/>';
            }

        }
```

Assim você poderia evitar loops desnecessários e reatribuição de valores para um array (pois da maneira estruturada, você tem que fazer **dois loops**). Também dispensa verificação de `'.'` e `'..'`, pois `FileSystemIterator` possui um método chamado `FileSystemIterator::isFile` para verificar se o sistema de arquivo atual é uma pasta ou um arquivo.